# Display average "Votes: Value" as stars in Views

Tags: 7, views, rating

I have created a table in Views 3 where ratings are averaged according to days of a week. But the ratings are showing as values between 1-100.

How can i convert these values in star rating from 1 to 5? I am unable to make it work either using Rate or Fivestar modules. I would prefer a solution through views ui but dont mind alternatives.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be easy with a simple theme file.
In the views interface, on the bottom right, you should see "Theme: informtion", click that and you will see relevant theme file names.
Using one like "views-view-field--rating.tpl.php" should work.

Comment: I am not a coder but i added this in the suggested template file..print round($output/20,1);. This formats the values between a range of 1-5. Hopefully this is the right way to do it, but anyway it works the way i intend to. Thanks for the pointer.